# Can PHP foreach statements have if/else inside them?

Tags: php, string, function, opencart

I am doing an OpenCart modification to an order total. This is the snippet of the code:

```
<?php
foreach ($data['totals'] as $total) {
    if (
        $this->db->escape($total['code'])=="sub_total" ||
        $this->db->escape($total['title'])="Sub-Total" 
    ) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . (float)$data['total'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
    } else {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . $_SESSION['GCFinalOrderTotalIncludingDelivery'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
    }
}
?>
```

This is the pseudo code. Can an IF/Else be nested inside the foreach statement?

```
<?php
foreach ($d['totals'] as $total) {
    if ($query=="x" ||  $query=="y") {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely no reason why not, did you even try it?

Comment: Huh? It's totally allowed in there Petah. if's can go inside them absolutely

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, For OpenCart questions you may want to try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenCart the file you're trying to edit I assume is the Order Model?

**[/catalog/model/checkout/order.php](http://code.google.com/p/opencart/source/browse/trunk/upload/catalog/model/checkout/order.php?r=1048)**

You have a problem with missing two `==` which was mentioned by [FAngel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558311/fangel) but the problem lies with your float. The data attribute gets taken away in this function. Because the Data array is no longer inside that snippet. It relies on TOTAL:

So your line:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . (float)$data['total'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
```

should be: (notice the NEW `(float)$total['value']`)

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . (float)$total['value'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
```

Which means it would be:

```
#######
// WAS (float)$data['value'] 
// NOW (float)$total['value']
#######
foreach ($data['totals'] as $total) {
    if (
    $this->db->escape($total['code'])=="sub_total" ||
    $this->db->escape($total['title'])=="Sub-Total" 
    ) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . (float)$total['value'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
    } else {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($total['code']) . "', title = '" . $this->db->escape($total['title']) . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape($total['text']) . "', `value` = '" . $_SESSION['GCFinalOrderTotalIncludingDelivery'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$total['sort_order'] . "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much +1 for the level of detail! The `==` was not the only issue, the data and total replace worked! My database is being updated with the right values now! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Sure they can.

And it is quite hard to use 30 characters to say that.

Comment: +1 for using _And it is quite hard to use 30 characters to say that_ to fill those characters ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Repped for the humorous approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it can. Not clear what is your problem, but suppose you have a typo in this line:

```
$this->db->escape($total['title']) = "Sub-Total"
```

which should be like this:

```
$this->db->escape($total['title']) == "Sub-Total"
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing this +1, the author who answered the question highlighted this and reference you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. It is pretty commonly done too. Make sure you use `==` when testing though; you have `=` as your test.

Comment: or actually I'd say make sure you use '==='...

Comment: yes fair point, although sometimes you don't want to force a type match. For instance, a database may return 0s and 1s and the code base may want to use true/false. always better to have consistent types but lets be honest, who works on ideal code base/db setups? only the lucky few...

Comment: Given your example, database might return false on problem with a query, which would with '==' get interpreted as 0. You really don't want the same handling for both.

Comment: This is absolutely the case and probably shows my example is not that good. Take the example of php passing a transaction value as a string because the ecom system you work on does not cast as a float. you match with type and the ecom engine throws a fit and dies. this is not because you were wrong to use the type match - you were correct. the problem is in the code base you are employing. this is not an uncommon thing to see. it is a shame because type matching and casting does make the life of a dev a bit easier and more predictable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you know by now that: *"Yes, they can!"*. However: if your loop isn't that big, you might want to rethink what the actual difference is between the two branches. Take your pseudo-code example, for instance: if the branch is decided on depending on a value that is not derived from the variables provided by the loop itself, you're better of moving the branch:

```
foreach($someArr as $k=>$v)
{
    if ($someOtherVar === true)
    {
        echo 'The value is '.$v;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'The key is '.$k;
    }
}
```

Can (and should) be written as:

```
$str = 'The '.($someOtherVar === true ? 'value' : 'key').' is ';
foreach($someArr as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $str.$v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely.Else what would have been the point in having a Programing Language.